# Import modules for testing with Pytest

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

[image: screenshot of Microsoft Visual Code]

I'm trying to test my code with Pytest framework, but for some reason I don't succeed importing my own code...

Answer (score 0):

You have to import your code from the top module, like this:

```
from se2pdf.se2pdf import changeFileExtensionToPDF
```

the first se2pdf is the folder name and the second your file name. If it doesn't work, make sure there is a _*init*_.py file in the modules.